# Docker private registry not working over HTTPs

Tags: docker

I setup a docker private registry, tried it one time with Ubuntu 22, and another time on CentOS 8. Both same problem.
I need the registry to be opened with HTTPs, not HTTP.

I followed the following tutorial: https://www.learnitguide.net/2018/07/create-your-own-private-docker-registry.html

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 \
-v /docker_data/images:/var/lib/registry \
-v /docker_data/certs:/certs \
-e registry_http_tls_certificate=/certs/domain.crt \
-e registry_http_tls_key=/certs/domain.key \
--restart=always \
--name registry \
```

I am using self-signed certificate.

This is the error I am getting when I login with docker:

**Error response from daemon: Get "https://FQDN:5000/v2/": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your server running on HTTPS? by looking at the error it seems like the server is returning an HTTP response whereas the client is trying to use HTTPS.

Comment: yes this is what seems to be, but I am not sure how to enable HTTPs for docker private registry I created?
I tried to add "insecure-registries": ["https://FQDN:5000"] to daemon.json, but did not solve the problem.